# What's the method to get the webkit webview's currently selected text?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk3, textselection, getselection

Using webkit version 1.6 I have been trying to figure out the class method/function to get the currently selected text. There's has_selection, but that only returns a bool.

I'm on linux mint using python gtk3 with webkit 1.6.

If I have to I'll use javascript, but I'd prefer a webkit method.

I don't really need a listener or signal. An event already creates a popup. I want to print the selected text in the popup.

I've tried:

webkit.webview.get_selected_text()

webkit.webview.get_selection()

webkit.webview.selected_text()

webkit.webview.get_property("selected-text")

Just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no special method for webkit to get selected text.

For now the gtk clipboard works to get text from a selection in the webkit.webview.

Use:

```
c = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY)
print c.wait_for_text()
```

It's a little funky, but it works.

Comment: Looks like this method interferes with execCommand in javascript used with webview.execute_javascript. I don't know if this is a bug, or it's to be expected.

Comment: The problem is wait_for_text deselects the text it retrieves. Any one have an idea to fix this?